# Excel Conditional statement

Tags: excel

i need to write a formula in excel that will perform comparison only if the value is available. i've two columns that will check to see if the amount matches, but could have a blank column, so don't want to perform any comparison when the field is blank. and is there a way that i can hide the formula. example:

jan feb Diff
15900   15880   Not same
10770
9360
7040    7195    Not same
12820   12820   same

Comment: can you tell me why 15900 and 15880 are the same when they do not equal each other?

Comment: i'm sorry ,, Typo

Comment: please fix the typos so we can know better what you want.

Comment: 7040 <> 7195 yet you still have it marked the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

=IF(AND(A2<>"",B2<>""),IF(A2=B2,"Same","Not Same"),"")